# android webview meaningless error android.webkit.WebView QuickSelect.resumeSelection nullpointerexception

Tags: android, webview

In my google android developer account I got this error . I checked the code but it seems to meaningless for me . I googled it and there is no result? Can anyone help me ?

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
at android.webkit.WebView$QuickSelect.resumeSelection(WebView.java:14232)
at android.webkit.WebView$QuickSelect$EventHub.handleMessage(WebView.java:14690)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:150)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4385)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:849)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:607)
at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```